# Better way to show that $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+a+1 \neq 1$

Tags: summation

Better way to show that $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+a+1 \neq 1$

The way that I am currently trying is to show that 
$$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+a+1 \neq 1$$
$$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+a \neq 0$$

I then follow with a wishy washy argument about how if a is negative the terms will alternate in sign but not cancel each other out and how if a is positive we get a large number. Is there a more straightforward way to show this? Thanks.

Comment: They are geometric sums. Googling a bit, or searching in this web, you will find a lot about geometric sums.

Comment: The sum is $1$ if for example $a=0$, or $n=1\,$. What are the conditions you are assuming?

Comment: I am working on proving that if $a^n-1$ is prime then a=2 and n is prime. Basically, $a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots +a +1$. since $a^n-1$ is prime, one of the factors has to be 1, so I am trying to show that $(a-1)=1 \rightarrow a=2$. I need that $(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots +a +1$. since $a^n-1$ ins't one I think.

Comment: @Math4Life Then you have already that $a \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2\,$ so the sum is always $\ge 2\,$.

Comment: What makes you say that I already have those conditions? I am having trouble seeing that... thank you for the help

Comment: The statement you say you are trying to prove only makes sense for integer $a \ge 1$ (in fact $a \ge 2$ since $1^n-1=0$) and $n \ge 2\,$. But that's yours to spell out in the question, rather than leave to others to guess.

Comment: If $a = -1$ and $n = \text{odd}$, then you have equality, not inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} a^k = a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+a+1= \frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$. This is only 1 if $a=0$ or $n=1$. The conditions of the bigger problem show these conditions are not accurate. Thus in valid conditions, it is not equal to 1.

Comment: Or $a = -1$ and $n$ is odd.